qemu cannot find root device to mount
I were emulating an embedded linux system of FlyOS.img which includes DOS/MBR boot sector and two partitions,before that I had extracted vmlinuz and initrd.img from the boot partition of the img,the qemu command was executed as below:
qemu-system-aarch64 \
-M virt \
-m 1024 \
-cpu cortex-a53 \
-kernel vmlinuz \
-initrd initrd.img \
-drive file=FlyOS.img,format=raw,if=none,id=drive0 \
-device virtio-blk-device,drive=drive0 \
-append 'root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 noresume rw' \
-nographic

It did boot the img,but it stuck for a few seconds while mounting root system,then threw   Alert:device does not exists.Dropping to a shell! and dropped to initramfs.I have tried /dev/vda2,/dev/sda2 etc,none of them works.May someone help me figure out the exact problem.

"I have tried /dev/vda2, /dev/sda2, etc..." -- don't just try random device names. When you drop to the initramfs shell, what block devices are visible in /dev? Are you certain that partition 2 is the root partition? Can you provide us with a link to the image you're using?

@larsks There are no block devices except  for loop0 to loop7,so obviously the requested partition or any other valid device is not mounted.The img above was created by dd the Voron0.2 embedded SD card system files which could be read by DiskInternals Linux Reader on Windows OS that it contains a Linux Ext / partialion and Fat16 BOOT partition.
